Python with Oanda API response 400 due to 'instrument missing'. In postman, the same data works when the request is sent
This is one of my first python projects, I have tested the json output from the python app in postman with the exact same URL and the correct authentication. When i send the request through python, the API responds with 400 (Bad Request) Order Reject.... 'Reject Reason : INSTRUMENT_MISSING'. However, in my code I have clearly defined the instrument and it is evident in the JSON which I have also tested in postman. I have resorted to stackoverflow as the Oanda docs on these erros are quite minmal.
def market_order(order: MarketOrderRequest):
    api = v20.Context(config.hostname, config.port, token=config.token)
    order_data = json.dumps(order.to_dict())
    response = api.order.market(account_id, data=order_data})
    print("Response: {} ({})".format(response.status, response.reason))
    print_order_create_response_transactions(response)


def main():
    order = MarketOrderRequest(
        instrument="XAU_USD",
        units=-97,
        takeProfitOnFill=TakeProfitOnFill(price=2450.800),
        stopLossOnFill=StopLossOnFill(price=24800.800)
    )
    print(order.to_dict())
    market_order(order)

Here is my current code, with the relevent classes used being model classes I have made. Trying to follow the MVC design pattern as best as I can.
Here are the console logs:
Response: 400 (Bad Request)
Order Reject
============

====================  ==============================
Transaction ID        72
Time                  2024-07-17T17:59:26.198868986Z
User ID               29511400
Account ID            101-004-XXXXX
Transaction Batch ID  72
Request ID            61262595850907041
Type                  MARKET_ORDER_REJECT
Time In Force         FOK
Position Fill         DEFAULT
Reason                CLIENT_ORDER
Reject Reason         INSTRUMENT_MISSING
====================  ==============================

The JSON which is produced in the program looks like this:
{
    "order": {
        "instrument": "XAU_USD",
        "units": -97,
        "takeProfitOnFill": {
            "price": 2450,
            "timeInForce": "GTC"
        },
        "stopLossOnFill": {
            "price": 2480,
            "timeInForce": "GTC"
        },
        "positionFill": "OPEN_ONLY",
        "timeInForce": "FOK",
        "type": "MARKET"
    }
}

When sending a request with this body in postman, the order goes through on my oanda account so I am stumped. Any help would be much appreciated and if you need more info please let me know and I will provide! Thanks :)

Solved by
response = api.order.market(account_id, instrument=order.instrument, units=order.units)

although it would be nice to be able to parse a dictionary or json into the api.order.market function.
